# Javascript getElementsByTagName not pulling correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm working out bugs that a coworker left on a page that posts a form to an API, and receives the XML response in an iframe, then parses through the children with XML. The page is working in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox, but not IE 8.

the form:

```
<form action="../../includes/functions/ADapi.php" method="POST" target="response" id="addForm" >
<fields galore></fields galore>
</form

<iframe name="response" id="response" style="display:none;" ></iframe>
```

the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <xmlresponse>
  <DateTime>2012-04-26 15:36:47</DateTime> 
  <confirmationcode>success</confirmationcode> 
  </xmlresponse>
```

the javascript:

```
function getResponse()
    {
        var myIFrame = document.getElementById("response");
        var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('confirmationcode');
        var insertID = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('id');
        //var sql = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('SQL');
        var response = $(content).text();
        var responseID = $(insertID).text();
        //alert($(sql).text());

        if(response == "Success" || response == 'success')
        {
            if(mode == 'edit')
            {
                post_to_url("/edit-contact", {type: 'edit', cust: id, mod: 'update',field : '<?php if(isset($_POST['field'])){ echo $_POST['field']; }?>',operator : '<?php if(isset($_POST['operator'])){ echo $_POST['operator']; }?>',criteria : '<?php if(isset($_POST['criteria'])){ echo $_POST['criteria']; }?>'});
            }
            else
            {
                post_to_url("/edit-contact", {type: 'edit', cust: responseID, mod: 'insert',field : '<?php if(isset($_POST['field'])){ echo $_POST['field']; }?>',operator : '<?php if(isset($_POST['operator'])){ echo $_POST['operator']; }?>',criteria : '<?php if(isset($_POST['criteria'])){ echo $_POST['criteria']; }?>'});
            }

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Error!");
        }


    }
```

each time it runs, it pops up the alert with 'Error!'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other possibilities for `response` to contain? Have you dropped `console.log(response);` into the `else`? Incidentally, debugging with `alert()`? Don't. It's incredibly intrusive, and you spend ridiculous amounts of time dismissing the things rather than working and following the flow. IE9 is pretty up-to-date, what does IE 7 do? if 9 works, and 7 doesn't, it suggests that something you depend on was added in pre IE9 release.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but: why would you put that response in an iframe?  Why wouldn't you just use an Ajax request using XmlHttpRequest, and parse the response?

Comment: I didn't build it. I'm just trying to fix it. It's a low priority bug, but I don't have time to rebuild it using AJAX by tomorrow at 10 in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with rebuilding the page to use AJAX. It took longer than it needed to, but I transferred it over. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340750/709941), it doesn't work the way it was set up, and needed something else to be done so it would be functional.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 only recognizes elements that are valid in HTML, if you are querying from an HTML document (`window.document`). It works correctly if you are querying an XML document (like what's returned by an `XmlHttpRequest`).